# join more than 2 tables using SWQL(SolarWinds Query Language) when there is no common field?

Tags: .net, vb.net, solarwinds-orion

I am monitoring my node using SolarWinds Orion NPM (network performance monitoring). And I am using Orion SDK for getting alert information from SWIS (SolarWinds informarion Service) into vb.net console application.

I am using some vb.net code:

```
Function GetOneAlert(ByVal swis As InformationServiceClient) As AlertInfo
    Dim query As String, result As XElement
    query = "SELECT TOP 1 A.AlertDefID, A.ActiveObject, A.ObjectType FROM Orion.AlertStatus A WHERE A.Acknowledged=0 ORDER BY A.TriggerTimeStamp DESC"
    result = swis.QueryXml(query)
```

The problem is, I want to get `alertinforamtion` from three tables named `Orion.AlertDefinitions`, `Orion.AlertStatus` and`Orion.Nodes` in `swis` (SolarWinds Information Service) and I need to join these 3 tables but I can able to join 2 of them (`Orion.AlertDefinitions`, `Orion.AlertStatus`) using `swql` (SolarWinds Query Language) query shown below

```
query = "SELECT AlertStatus.AlertDefID, AlertDefinitions.AlertDefID, AlertDefinitions.Name, AlertStatus.State, AlertStatus.ObjectName, 
AlertStatus.TriggerTimeStamp, AlertDefinitions.Description FROM Orion.AlertStatus INNER JOIN Orion.AlertDefinitions
ON AlertStatus.AlertDefID=AlertDefinitions.AlertDefID WHERE AlertStatus.Acknowledged=0"
```

I know the alert details but i don't know the alert belongs to which node. For this purpose i need to join "orion.node" table with the remaining tables. But 3rd table (`Orion.Nodes`) has no common field(s) in anyone of other two tables to join.
I need to get three field values named as `DNS`, `IPAddress`, `NodeDescription` from `Orion.Nodes` table.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in node-related alerts and you want to join node details, then you should select only alerts with `AlertStatus.ObjectType='Node'` and join using `AlertStatus.ActiveObject` which is the `NodeID` of node associated. So the query (with node properties mentioned) would look like:

```
SELECT AlertStatus.AlertDefID, AlertDefinitions.AlertDefID, AlertDefinitions.Name, AlertStatus.State, AlertStatus.ObjectName, AlertStatus.TriggerTimeStamp, AlertDefinitions.Description, Nodes.IPAddress, Nodes.Dns, Nodes.NodeDescription
FROM Orion.AlertStatus
INNER JOIN Orion.AlertDefinitions
  ON AlertStatus.AlertDefID=AlertDefinitions.AlertDefID
INNER JOIN Orion.Nodes
  ON AlertStatus.ActiveObject=Nodes.NodeID
WHERE AlertStatus.Acknowledged=0 AND AlertStatus.ObjectType='Node'
```

Anyway, for more specific questions and answers about Orion SDK and SWIS, you might want to take a look at the [Orion SDK Thwack Forum](http://thwack.solarwinds.com/community/labs_tht/orion-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

There are also automatic associations made between the tables in SWQL, for example the SWQL below does not use `JOINs` but calls from several tables:

```
SELECT E0.[Node].Caption, E0.AssignmentName, E0.CustomPollerName, 
       E0.DetailsUrl, E0.DisplayName, E0.NodeID, E0.Status, E0.StatusDescription, 
       E0.StatusIconHint, E0.StatusLED, E0.UnManaged, E0.UnManageFrom, E0.UnManageUntil, E0.Uri, 
       E0.[Node].Description, E0.[CustomPoller].[OID] = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3',
       E0.[CustomPollerStatusScalar].[Status]
 FROM  Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignmentOnNode AS E0
 WHERE E0.[Node].[SysObjectID] IS NOT NULL
   AND E0.StatusDescription NOT LIKE 'Unmanaged'
```

[This site provides some more details and examples.](https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Network_Performance_Monitor_(NPM)/How_to_use_SolarWinds_Query_Language_(SWQL))